# Do we need to configure or autoload something for malsup.com/jquery/form/ to work in codeigniter

Tags: jquery, ajax, forms, codeigniter, file-upload

I am trying to upload a form with image and other inputs using ajax. I am using

http://malsup.com/jquery/form/#ajaxForm for it. When I worked without Codeigniter everything worked fine. But when I integrated the code in my view and then submitted the form, it is loading a new page i.e the one given in action. if I remove the action and put a url in the script nothing happen - its as if the script is not being called. Here's my code :-

```
 <html>
 <head>

 <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7/jquery.js"></script> 
 <script src="http://malsup.github.com/jquery.form.js"></script> 

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    var options = { 
        clearForm: true,
        resetForm: true
    };
    // bind 'myForm' and provide a simple callback function 
    $('#myForm').ajaxForm(function() { 
        //alert("Thank you for your comment!"); 

    }); 
    $('#myForm').ajaxForm(options);

}); 
</script> 

</head>

<body>
<form id="myForm" name="myForm" action="/main/comment" method="post"   enctype="multipart/form-data"> 
<input type="text" name="name" />
<br /> 
<textarea name="comment"></textarea> 
<br />
<input type="file" value="Share a Pic" name="file" id="file" />
<br />
<input type="submit" value="Submit Comment" /> 
</form>
</body>
```

Comment: These might help

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3841286/codeigniter-how-to-include-javascript-files

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1543407/codeigniter-how-do-i-include-a-js-file-in-view

Comment: hi, these are for including js files. But my js script is in the view itself, I am not making a separate file