# Codeigniter: include js files ci folder is installed outside http folder

Tags: codeigniter

I am new in CI - and the framework is awesome.

These are the best answers I can get:
 - [CodeIgniter: How do I include a .js file in view?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1543407/codeigniter-how-do-i-include-a-js-file-in-view)
 - [Codeigniter: How to include javascript files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3841286/codeigniter-how-to-include-javascript-files)

I am trying to include js/css files but:
My CI folder including application and system are not installed on the http(/var/www/)[for default installation] folder, I placed somewhere else. So i assume their installations above are in http default folder, I have :

http:
/var/www
CI:
/opt/codeigniter

+aplication
   +system

Thank you so much in advance

Comment: `base_url()` will return your project path. Then you can use `../` to include file with the correct path.

Comment: thanks @kumar_v i actually didnt get it so clearly, Im sorry, but I will try it.. am still puzzling it... is it base_url /../js/jquery.js or ../ base_url /js/jquery.js - thank you for the reply

Answer (score 0):

Use this code

```
<script href="<?php base_url().'path/to/file' ?>" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

The javascript folder should be outside the application folder

app_folder

-application

--views

--controllers

-system

-css

-js

Hope this helps

Comment: thank you @hubert I tried it and still no luck, I guess i will have to place my js/css files in my http folder